# Adding data from json into html table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am trying to build a table, where first cell is an image , next cells have some values, for which header is defined in thead.
The issue is that, in javascript, for every iteration of loop, it adds a new row, though I have not used `<tr>`

```js
fetch("./static/js/data.json")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
      let imgsrc = data.data[j].image;
      document.querySelector("#userdata").innerHTML += 
        `<tr><td rowspan="8"><img src=${imgsrc} width="150" height="150"></td>`;
      for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        let vmovieID = data.data[j].ingredients[i].contents;
        document.querySelector("#userdata").innerHTML += `<td>${vmovieID}</td>`;
      }
    }
    document.querySelector("#userdata").innerHTML += '</tr>'
  });
```

```html
<div class="panel-body">
  <table id="userdata">
    <thead>
      <th>Image</th>
      <th>Dry Matter</th>
      <th>CP</th>
      <th>GE</th>
      <th>Calcium</th>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

Results are:
[image]

Comment: Instead of adding to the innerHTML at each step, try constructing the whole HTML string first, and then adding it one time. This way you can also print out the HTML to be added, and see what that looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's recommended to use Javascript to create and append the elements as variables, rather than appending strings of HTML at various points.

Additionally, you should confirm the DOM is loaded before targeting elements to avoid any bugs.

Refactored code with the points from above:

```html
<script>
  
  const fetchedData = fetch("./static/js/data.json");

  window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {

    fetchedData
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        
        const table = document.getElementById("userdata");

        for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
          const imgsrc = data.data[j].image;
          const row = document.createElement("tr");
          row.innerHTML = `<td rowspan="8"><img src=${imgsrc} width="150" height="150"></td>`;

          for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            const vmovieID = data.data[j].ingredients[i].contents;
            const textContent = document.createTextNode(vmovieID);
            const cell = document.createElement("td");
            cell.appendChild(textContent);
            row.appendChild(cell);
          }

          table.appendChild(row);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(new Error(error));
      });
  });
</script>

<div class="panel-body">
  <table id="userdata">
    <thead>
      <th>Image</th>
      <th>Dry Matter</th>
      <th>CP</th>
      <th>GE</th>
      <th>Calcium</th>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```